# Setting version field explicitly in ORMLite

Tags: android, ormlite

Using ORMLite on Android we are using the version annotation in order to use a modified field as a versioning status. However, our client/server sync mechanism works in a way that the server tells us when the object has changed(because the user might changed the object on a different platform/device) and gives us the updated object.

**Now the problem:**

Suppose i have the following code to update a given document:

```
Document newDoc = new Document(jsonDocument);
Document oldDoc = ormDBhelp.getDocumentDao().queryForId(newDoc.getfId());
Document.transplantLocalFields(oldDoc, newDoc);
ormDBhelper.getDocumentDao().update(newDoc);
```

This update command fails, because our newDoc already has a newer modified field(and thus the WHERE version=current-version contraint fails). Now one could argue to call `newDoc.modified=oldDoc.modified` and just let it update with the current Date of the local client. But this would be wrong, because the actual modified date was not the moment where we persited it in our local DB, but instead when it was modified on the server.

*So is there any way to explicitly set the version? Or to ignore the version contraints for a single request?*

Thx in advance! Maybe i just oversee something, or we just have to manually manage the version field and completely omit the version annotation of ORMLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there any way to explicitly set the version? Or to ignore the version contraints for a single request?

You can (of course) do a `dao.refresh(...)` on the entity to get the latest version from the entity before you update it.  That's the right thing to do most likely.

However, as a hack, if you need to specifically change the version then you could create 2 entities that both go to the same table.  One of the entities would have the `version` field as `version=true` and the other would not.  You can then use the non-special `version` fieldto update the field directly.